# error in function definition or declaration; function not called

Tags: c++

So I'm new to C++ language and I'm not sure what is wrong with this code right. btw, this is not my code, it is from a book called Absolute C++ for Savitch.

I get following error messages: 
`overloaded function differs only by return type` and `error in function definition or declaration`

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int round(double number);
// Assumes number >= 0.
// Returns number rounded to the nearest integer.

int main()
{
    double doubleValue;
    char ans;

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter a double value: ";
        cin >> doubleValue;
        cout << "Rounded that number is " << round(doubleValue) << endl;
        cout << "Again? (y/n): ";
        cin >> ans;
    } while (ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y');
    cout << "End of testing.\n";

    return 0;
}

// Uses cmath:
int round(double number) 
{ 
    return static_cast<int>(floor(number + 0.5)); 
}
```

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) Your `round` is conflicting with `std::round`.

Comment: Also, we have [a list of good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) if you want to take a look.

Comment: Rename your `round` to `notstd_round`.